# OWIN - ResponseType <code> vs <idtoken> on AuthorizationCodeReceived

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, owin, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm using from KeyCloak for SSO (Single Sign On). And I have an ASP.NET MVC project to use from it.

I have this for sent request:

```
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
     ClientId = client_id,
     Authority = issuer_url,
     RedirectUri = redirect_uri,
     PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirect_uri,
     Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
     ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
     ClientSecret = secret,
     SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
     Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
     {
           AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
           AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
     },
});
```

And I get code `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived()`:

```
    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification n)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
        {
            Code = n.Code,
            Address = token_endpoint_url,
            ClientId = client_id,
            ClientSecret = secret,
            RedirectUri = redirect_uri,
        });

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
            throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);

        var response = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
        {
            Token = tokenResponse.AccessToken,
            Address = userinfo_endpoint,
        });

        if (response.IsError)
            throw new Exception(response.Error);

        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaims(response.Claims);
    }
```

When I use `ResponseType` only code, the `n.AuthenticationTicket` is NULL. And I must set response type as `codeIdtoken` to get `n.AuthenticationTicket` and I fill claims. Also I have to enable Hybrid Flow on KeyCloak.

I don't want to change my code on changing flows (Standard Flow Enabled or Implicit Flow Enabled).

Is it possible that I get `n.AuthenticationTicket` on `ResponseType.Code`?

Note: I don`t have any problem on get` n.code`also`tokenResponse.AccessToken`but my problem is only on` n.AuthenticationTicket`.

If it is not possible, what is the standard solution for filling claims?

Answer (score 0):

if you just use ResponseType **code**, you will get the access token or authorization code, but they are not related  to the AuthenticationTicket.

The **AuthenticationTicket** is created based on the **ID-token**, because that contains the details about the user. So you need to use **code id_token** to get it to work.

For modern application and to follow best practices, you should only aim to use the **authorization code flow** or the **client credentials flow.**

Some parts of the standards are no longer considered secure and if you follow [OAuth 2.1](https://oauth.net/2.1/) then the two flows above are the ones that are recommended.

**OAuth 2.1** is a summary of **OAuth 2.0** +/- all the **best practices** that has been established since 2.0 was released.

For the example, the **Implicit grant** (response_type=token) is omitted from this specification. You can still use it, but it is no longer considered best practice.

Comment: Hi. I can`t understand your last statement? "For modern application and to follow best practices, you should only aim to use the authorization code flow or the client credentials flow." Please explain more. Thank U.

Comment: Updated my answer and is this an acceptable answer?